# md-datepicker is not working with focus out

Tags: angular, typescript

```
<md-input-container *ngIf="type==='date'">
  <input mdInput [mdDatepicker]="picker" (focusout)="hideEdit() [value]="value" placeholder="Choose a date">
  <button mdSuffix [mdDatepickerToggle]="picker"></button>
  <md-datepicker #picker ></md-datepicker>
</md-input-container>
```

I am trying to tab to the datepicker cell, and try to focus out after the calendar is closed.

Comment: You're missing a " ....

Comment: it was a typo. My actual code has the ".